# Cant ping over direct fiber connection using static ip addresses win10 to ubuntu 20.04

Tags: windows-10, networking, ubuntu-20.04, 10gbit

So far have not been able to get my pc direct connected to my server and I am hoping someone can see where I have gone wrong or what I have missed. I have searched through many posts and spent some time trying everything that I know.
[Windows is showing that the adapter is connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYdPT.png)

ubuntu is showing the adapter as down until i run "ip link set enp4s0 up"
on ubuntu the 10gbe adapter that i am have this issue with is enp4s0

I have 2 machines connected with 2 nics each.

One Gbe adapter connects to the wider lan 192.168.0.0, and a 10gb spf+ Mellanox connectx-3 connecting directly between the machines on the 192.168.2.0 network. Both machines have matching Mellanox cards and transceivers

I am using these transceivers
[FS for Mellanox MFM1T02A-SR Compatible 10GBASE-SR SFP+](https://www.fs.com/products/65334.html)

**Win 10 network settings**

static ip

ip addr: 192.168.2.2/24

gateway:

dns:

[Win 10 network settings image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTuAF.jpg)

**Ubuntu 20.04 network settings**

```
root@budnas:/home/bud# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:a6:ba:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp9s0
    inet 192.168.0.200/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic eno1
       valid_lft 85824sec preferred_lft 85824sec
    inet6 2600:8801:b000:3200:225:90ff:fea6:ba00/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 86399sec preferred_lft 86399sec
    inet6 fe80::225:90ff:fea6:ba00/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eno2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:a6:ba:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp10s0
4: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:1d:2d:4f:df:c0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

root@budnas:/home/bud# ip link set enp4s0 up
root@budnas:/home/bud# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:a6:ba:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp9s0
    inet 192.168.0.200/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic eno1
       valid_lft 85646sec preferred_lft 85646sec
    inet6 2600:8801:b000:3200:225:90ff:fea6:ba00/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 86393sec preferred_lft 86393sec
    inet6 fe80::225:90ff:fea6:ba00/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eno2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:a6:ba:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp10s0
4: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:1d:2d:4f:df:c0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::e61d:2dff:fe4f:dfc0/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

root@budnas:/home/bud# nano /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
    eno2:
      optional: true
    enp9s0:
      optional: true
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
    enp10s0:
      optional: true
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
    enps4s0:
      optional: true
      addresses: ['192.168.2.3/24']

root@budnas:/home/bud# netplan generate
root@budnas:/home/bud# netplan apply

root@budnas:/home/bud# ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.200 metric 100
192.168.0.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.200
192.168.0.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.200 metric 100

root@budnas:/home/bud# flint -d /dev/mst/mt4099_pci_cr0 query
Image type:            FS2
FW Version:            2.42.5000
FW Release Date:       5.9.2017
Product Version:       02.42.50.00
Rom Info:              type=PXE version=3.4.752
Device ID:             4099
Description:           Node             Port1            Port2            Sys image
GUIDs:                 ffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffff
MACs:                                       e41d2d4fdfc0     e41d2d4fdfc1
VSD:
PSID:                  MT_1170110023

root@budnas:/home/bud# lshw -c network
*-network
     description: Ethernet interface
     product: MT27500 Family [ConnectX-3]
     vendor: Mellanox Technologies
     physical id: 0
     bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
     logical name: enp4s0
     version: 00
     serial: e4:1d:2d:4f:df:c0
     size: 10Gbit/s
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm vpd msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical fibre
     configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=mlx4_en driverversion=4.0-0 duplex=full firmware=2.42.5000 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=fibre speed=10Gbit/s
     resources: irq:35 memory:fb300000-fb3fffff memory:f4000000-f47fffff memory:fb200000-fb2fffff
*-network
     description: Ethernet interface
     product: 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 0
     bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
     logical name: eno1
     version: 00
     serial: 00:25:90:a6:ba:00
     size: 1Gbit/s
     capacity: 1Gbit/s
     width: 32 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
     configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.13.0-39-generic duplex=full firmware=2.1-2 ip=192.168.0.200 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
     resources: irq:18 memory:fb500000-fb51ffff ioport:c000(size=32) memory:fb520000-fb523fff
*-network
     description: Ethernet interface
     product: 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 0
     bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
     logical name: eno2
     version: 00
     serial: 00:25:90:a6:ba:01
     capacity: 1Gbit/s
     width: 32 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
     configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.13.0-39-generic firmware=2.1-2 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
     resources: irq:19 memory:fb400000-fb41ffff ioport:b000(size=32) memory:fb420000-fb423fff
```

**@Preston Maness**
Good idea but I still can not successfully ping.

**Windows routing table**

```
C:\Windows\system32>route -p add 192.168.2.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.2.2
 OK!

C:\Windows\system32>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
  6...24 8a 07 5d a1 20 ......Mellanox ConnectX-3 Ethernet Adapter
  7...2c f0 5d 9f 0d df ......Realtek PCIe 2.5GbE Family Controller
 17...0a 00 27 00 00 11 ......VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
 15...00 50 56 c0 00 01 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
  4...c8 e2 65 f8 dc 38 ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1     192.168.0.27     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.0.27    281
     192.168.0.27  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.27    281
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.27    281
      192.168.2.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.2.2    271
      192.168.2.2  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.2.2    271
    192.168.2.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.2.2    271
     192.168.56.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.56.1    281
     192.168.56.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    281
   192.168.56.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    281
    192.168.248.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.248.1    291
    192.168.248.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.248.1    291
  192.168.248.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.248.1    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.56.1    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.248.1    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.0.27    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.2.2    271
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.248.1    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.27    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.2.2    271
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
      192.168.2.0    255.255.255.0      192.168.2.2       1
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  7    281 ::/0                     fe80::96a6:7eff:fe1e:8976
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
  7    281 2600:8801:b000:3200::/56 fe80::96a6:7eff:fe1e:8976
  7    281 2600:8801:b000:3200::/64 On-link
  7    281 2600:8801:b000:3200:796a:e24a:3c16:4e89/128
                                    On-link
  7    281 2600:8801:b000:3200:b18e:3579:377d:ce14/128
                                    On-link
 17    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 15    291 fe80::/64                On-link
  7    281 fe80::/64                On-link
  6    271 fe80::/64                On-link
 17    281 fe80::c1f:2e81:f19f:281d/128
                                    On-link
 15    291 fe80::4487:9c20:68a9:f2c6/128
                                    On-link
  7    281 fe80::b18e:3579:377d:ce14/128
                                    On-link
  6    271 fe80::e086:b8e9:d6a2:68ca/128
                                    On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
 17    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
 15    291 ff00::/8                 On-link
  7    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
  6    271 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

**new ubuntu routing table**

```
bud@budnas:~$ ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.200 metric 100
192.168.0.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.200
192.168.0.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.200 metric 100
192.168.2.0/24 dev enp4s0 scope link
192.168.2.2 dev enp4s0 scope link
```

Comment: I don't know about the Windows side of things, but on the Ubuntu side, I suspect that [a route is missing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238132/direct-connection-w-ethernet-cable). Currently, packets destined to the 192.168.2.0/24 network will hit the default route (`default via 192.168.0.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.200 metric 100`). I suspect you'll need to add an explicit route for pushing those packets over the interface a la `ip r add 192.168.2.0/24 dev enps4s0` for the subnet or `ip r add 192.168.2.2/32 dev enps4s0` for the windows host specifically.

Comment: good thought, but after adding the routes I still could not ping. what is odd to me is that I can not see the ip4 address I set for the enp4s0 interface when looking at "ip addr". the ip6 address shows, but only after I "ip link set enp4s0 up"

Comment: That sounds like the last missing piece (assuming no other blockers like firewall rules preventing ICMP packets). Are you able to manually add the IP address to the interface with `ip addr add dev enps4s0 192.168.2.3/24`? I'm not familiar with netplan specifically, so I wonder if it might be either silently failing to properly set up the `enps4s0` interface (maybe needs on-link config?) or else immediately reverting any custom changes you make.

Comment: per your suggestion, after running both of the following commands it works, but it is not persistent through restart.
sudo ip addr add dev enp4s0 192.168.2.3/24
sudo ip link set enp4s0 up

Comment: the command you gave me led me to the correct answer. I had misspelled the interface name in the config file. the interface is enp4s0, and I had put enps4s0 in the config file. thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Awesome! Sneaky typos, sneaking past our diligent eyes :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, typos strike again :) The `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` had a typo:

```
root@budnas:/home/bud# nano /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
    eno2:
      optional: true
    enp9s0:
      optional: true
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
    enp10s0:
      optional: true
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
    # Problem below; should be enp4s0, not enps4s0
    enps4s0:
      optional: true
      addresses: ['192.168.2.3/24']
```

(`enps4s0` should be `enp4s0`.)

I also suspect you'd need the added routes on the Windows side.

In summary, for establishing connections between hosts that are directly connected:

1. Ensure both hosts have IP addresses in the same subnet, associated to the interface that is directly connected ("on-link").
2. Ensure both hosts have routes instructing traffic to that subnet to be pushed directly out of the interface ("on-link") and not forwarded to a gateway.